# SSRS Not sorting correctly

Tags: sql-server, sorting, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I'm tapping into a SQL Server 2014 database using SSRS 2014. I've used SSRS from its initial release but have never experienced this problem so I don't know if its a bug in SSRS 2014. I have a stored procedure that returns some data, something as simple as this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewsletterStories] 
    @NewsletterID int,
    @IsMainStory int=2 --2 is both, 1 is true, 0 is false
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ns.SortOrder as SortOrder,
        ns.Title,
        ns.Description,
        ns.LinkText,
        ns.LinkURL,
        ns.PictureName,
        ns.IsMainStory
    FROM
        NewsletterStory ns
    INNER JOIN
        Newsletter n
    ON
        n.NewsletterID = ns.NewsletterID
    WHERE
        n.Deleted=0
        AND ns.Deleted=0
        AND n.NewsletterID = @NewsletterID
        --do they want non main story or main story or both
        AND ((ns.IsMainStory = 0 AND @IsMainStory=0) OR (ns.IsMainStory = 1 AND @IsMainStory=1) OR (@IsMainStory=2))
    ORDER BY 
        ns.SortOrder
END
```

If I run the stored procedure from within Management Studio like so:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetNewsletterStories]
        @NewsletterID = 1,
        @IsMainStory = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I get exactly what I need in the correct order:

[image]

Then I'm in SSRS and I create my dataset and can go to the query designer and run it:

[image]

Here is where it prompts me for my parameters:

[image]

I get exactly what I needed:

[image]

So far so good, I added my tablix and set its dataset name I created and even went as far as setting the sorting section to `[SortOrder]` based on the column in my dataset:

[image]

Every time I run my report I get the wrong sort order:

[image]

Simple I thought, it must be caching some old version, so I made sure to delete my reports `MyReport.rdl.data` file so that I get a fresh report. Nope that too still shows "Concerto Integration" first and then "RIMS Newsletter"...but my dataset and my stored procedure is returning the right order "RIMS Newsletter" and "Concerto Integration". I've tried everything but it always seems to be sorting by the primary key of the table (when the article was created, as I created the Concerto Integration article before the RIMS Newsletter article).

I don't know where else to look, I even inspected the resultant XML (view code feature) and the `SortOrder` is in the dataset. Even if I remove that `SortOrder` it should work because the stored procedure is already sorting by it as you see in the code.

What gives?

Comment: Do you have any groupings? If so, what is the sort order for your groups?

Comment: What about the details group?

Comment: FYI - In a later version of this report, there are two groups, "Title" and "Details2", as shown in the answer by @JonH

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow found it and as usual it is a bug in SSRS, I remember these sorts of things being bugs in SSRS 2005 and SSRS 2008.  So even if you change the SortOrder in the designer, in my case I changed it to SortOrder.  That didnt work...so what I did was right clicked on the actual report and did a "View Code".  And I looked for SortExpression and it did not have the value SortOrder, its almost like in some cases when you update the report from the designer the code xml portion does not see those updates.

Anyhow I changed it such that the XML read this:

```
 <SortExpressions>
                            <SortExpression>
                              <Value>=Fields!SortOrder.Value</Value>
                            </SortExpression>
                          </SortExpressions>
```

Saved my report and ran it again and voila, all is well now.  Lesson Learned to use prior experience with the "View Code" option to fix issues like this.

Here was the whole thing:

```
<TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Group Name="Title">
                        <GroupExpressions>
                          <GroupExpression>=Fields!Title.Value</GroupExpression>
                        </GroupExpressions>
                      </Group>
                      <SortExpressions>
                        <SortExpression>
                          <Value>=Fields!SortOrder.Value</Value>
                        </SortExpression>
                      </SortExpressions>
                      <TablixMembers>
                        <TablixMember>
                          <Group Name="Details2" />
                          <TablixMembers>
                            <TablixMember />
                            <TablixMember />
                            <TablixMember />
                          </TablixMembers>
                        </TablixMember>
                      </TablixMembers>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
```

Whatever I did in the designer would not update the sortexpression value portion, this portion:

```
<SortExpressions>
                        <SortExpression>
                          <Value>=Fields!SortOrder.Value</Value>
                        </SortExpression>
                      </SortExpressions>
```

I tried through the designer but it never updated the XML, and running the report produced the wrong result.  Its only until I manually changed the SortExpression to read Fields!SortOrder.Value did my report sort correctly.

Here's the screenshot as mentioned in the comments:

[image]

Better photo:

[image]

Even if I do it at the title level same issue:

[image]

Comment: What section of the XML was this found? Was the parent group a `<TablixMember>` or `<Tablix>`? If it was a `<TablixMember>`, then you may not have been looking in the correct place in the designer.

Comment: Brennan Pope, even if you set the property for the tablix member ( the sort property ) the XML doesnt pick it up...this has been a bug in SSRS since day one.  Try it out, its inside tablix member, set the sort via XML and look at the designer...then change htat same sort only in the designer.  The XML never gets updated!

Comment: There are multiple places you can set sort expressions. My guess is that you have a row group with a sort order specified. If you search the XML, is this the only `<SortExpression>` you find? The sort expressions for the tablix members are generally declared before the sort expressions for the tablix.

Comment: The screenshot of the designer (in your question) does not match this part of the XML. I will provide a walkthrough of how to view this in the designer.

Comment: I understand that because I had so many screen shots already...I can send that screen shot as well.

Comment: Brennan Pope I posted the screen shot in this answer.  Whatever I do in the designer against this sort order is not taken over to the XML.  Only after I do it directly in the XML does it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74741/discussion-between-brennan-pope-and-jonh).

Comment: I can't duplicate this issue, but I'm not go to go as far as to deny it's a bug. I'm going to leave this as an "I don't know." Thank you for providing details and answering my questions.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I think the sorting displayed in the above screenshot with the red arrow pointing at the middle detail row is the wrong grouping - your picture wouldn't be included. Is this tablix in another table? 
I certainly won't dent that there are plenty of bugs in SSRS that Microsoft refuses to fix but I'm not sure this is one of them.

Comment: Hannover take a look at the chat transcript, the picture was my bad...I should of given the picture showing the title grouping..its the same issue whether I use that.  So sorry about that one, whether I point to the title, the description or anything it still is the same issue.  If i fix the XML the designer gets updated, however, if I fix the designer the XML does not get updated - to me that is clearly a bug.  This bit me back in the 2005 RS and 2008 RS packages - it happens some times...just not all the time.  I added two more images, one showing that these are group rows.

Comment: Dang! This opened up my eyes and solved my problem. A little different but no matter. No value at all was set for the Tablix sort expression. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

SQL Server 2012

In row groups, I changed first columns sorting to what I want. Go to Row group> Change sorting as shown in figures. Also, I have changed the tablix sorting.

[image: RowGroup]
[image: Sort on first column of row group]

Comment: The figures seem to be missing here.  This was typed on 06/04/2020.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks - I had a spurious group which wasn't visible on the report. Deleting it fixed the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, it would only sort on the Group which was the name not the sort order that I wanted. Changing the Tablix's sort order had no affect. I was able to address it by going to the Group properties and selecting Sorting. In there I changed the "sort by" property from the datasets "name" field to the datasets "sortorder" field and that fixed it. The Sort Order at the Tablix level apparently is overridden by the groupings sort order.
Jay

Comment: Just wanted to add "Group Properties" option is available in "Row Groups" box.